# Send data from Nodejs API to Flask APi

Tags: python, node.js, postgresql, flask

so i am creating a small application in Nodejs and Flask. I have created 2 apis. First one sending data from Nodejs App to Nodejs API then sending the data from the Nodejs API to flask api.
I am having a bit of trouble sending the data from the Node Api to the Flask Api.

//send data from Node.js api to Flask Api

```
app.get('/postoflask',  (req, res) => {
 request('http://localhost:3030/users',  (error, response, bodyParser) => {
      if(error) {
          
          res.send(' erorr occured')
      }
  
      else {
          res.send(bodyParser)
          request.post('http://localhost:5000/adduser')
        }
  });
});
```

Deploying the route on the browser retrieves the data from the node Api database and pushes null values to the flask api database. i need the data retrieved from the Node Api to be transferred as it is to the database of the flask database.

port 3030/users is the node api that fetches data from database and port 5000/adduser is flask api to push data into database.

I am an entry to mid-level programmer, but i don't know what i am missing here or what i am not understanding. Help will be very appreciated. Database used is PostgreSql.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [request stream capabilities](https://github.com/request/request#streaming) in order to proxy data from Node.js endpoint to Flask:

```
app.get('/postoflask', (req, res) => {
  request('http://localhost:3030/users')
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      res.send('done')
    })
    .pipe(request.post('http://localhost:5000/adduser'));
})
```

Comment: This return 'done' and still sends null values to the database

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending any data in `request.post('http://localhost:5000/adduser')`, try

`request.post('http://localhost:5000/adduser',{...})`

Comment: res.send(bodyParser) , bodyParser contains the data from the database, this line of code returns the data in json format on the browser, when passing it in request.post('http://localhost:5000/adduser',bodyParser) , still pushes null values into the flask api database